# NavigationController Pushes View down on return

Tags: ios, navigationcontroller

I am using a Navigation Controller having 3 views. The 1st view has the Title Bar Hidden and the remaining views have it displayed. So I am hiding it in the first view in viewWillAppear() as

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

and in the second view, I'm displaying it

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
```

That being said, the title bar is hidden in the first view and shows up and works fine on the second and third views.

When I navigate from the first to the second view and to the third, everything works fine. But, when I go from the third view back to the second, the images are compressed by around the height of the title bar. And again works fine when I go from the first to the second view.

Comment: Post all code related to navigationBar you have in `-viewWillAppear` methods of your viewControllers please. it looks like you set tintColor property nil or use different navigationBar styles.

Comment: All my code is in the -viewWillAppear method. What is the tintColor? I have no idea? Also, what I was doing was I was leaving some space on the top for the title bar, turns out I don't have to do that. My Bad. But my Images are still being compressed by arnd 44 px. Eg I have my image height set to 58px and it only shows up as arnd 15px. Any Ideas? Thanx a lot, appreciate it!

Comment: What do you mean "compressed"? If navigationbar cuts your UIImageViews then you did not setup navigationBar properly. TintColor is a property of navigationbar, it should be not nil if your navigationbar should not be above view.

Comment: I have my image height set to 58px and it only shows up as arnd 15px. I used the tintColor property as     self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor]; Can you elaborate on what I have done wrong and what I need to setup in the navigationBar? Also, I did not get your last sentence "if your navigationbar should not be above view."

Comment: Try setiing on first viewControllerw in viewWillAppear tintColor=nil and navigationbarStyle BlackTranscluent, and on other viewControllers tintColor Black and navigationBarStyle Black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navigationbar.hidden property should not be set directly.  You should use:

```
if(self.navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden == NO)
  self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
```

Comment: What I was doing was I was leaving some space on the top for the title bar, turns out I don't have to do that. My Bad. But my Images are still being compressed by arnd 44 px. Eg I have my image height set to 58px and it only shows up as arnd 15px. Any Ideas? Thanx a lot, appreciate it!